# This is the error Android studio is showing me when i am pressing the button

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

*Logcat Output:*

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String firebase.firebasepractice.User.getUsername()' on a null object reference. ...

*User:*

[image: User class]

*MainActivity:*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private EditText name,password;
  Button btn;
  TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
    password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseReference myRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

                String userId=myRef.push().getKey();

            myRef.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    tv.setText("Name is "+user.getUsername()+"    Email is "+user.getEmail());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Add snapshot detail and User model

Comment: I have added snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Because mapping between datasnapshot and User model is failed.

```
User user=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
// check it null there
if(user != null) {
 tv.setText("Name is "+user.getUsername()+"    Email is "+user.getEmail());
}
```

Comment: the error message has gone but data is not retrieved from the firebase

Comment: @MaheshChandra Add datasnapshot of your Firebase and User java class in your question.

Comment: added snapshot..please help

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a no-args constructor in `User` class:

Please add:

```
public User() {
}
```

Then, you are initialising `myRef` like this:

```
myRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
```

And then again accessing 'Users' node under 'Users'

```
myRef.child("Users")
```

Lastly, I believe you are passing a wrong variable to a `.child()` call in:

```
myRef.child("Users")
    .addValueEventListener ...
```

You should be doing:

```
myRef.child(userId) // this line is changed
    .addValueEventListener ...
```

Your final code should look like:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

String userId = myRef.push().getKey();

myRef.child(userId) // Change: "Users" -> userId
    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            tv.setText("Name is " + user.getUsername() + "\tEmail is " + user.getEmail());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am still unable to fetch the result..

Comment: @MaheshChandra Please check my edits. You are accessing 'Users' under  'Users' node

Comment: tried this instead. Still nothing..

Comment: Please add no-args constructor as per edits.

Comment: please go through the snapshots. I have done edits but nothing worked

Comment: @MaheshChandra Maybe I am not seeing updated site. Did you add the no-argument constructor to User class?

Comment: @MaheshChandra Please do not make changes to the meaning of the initial question. This makes the question different than the one you posted first and readers are left confused when they go through answers. Thank you. :)